# Access SQL IIF statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access SQL query using an `iif` statement that is not evaluating correctly. I don't see the problem with the `iif` statement.

The following SQL code below yields the table below it.

```sql
SELECT PR, 
    G21_Start AS Genesis_Date, 
    SWITCH(G21_comp IS NULL, 2.1,
               G22_comp IS NULL, 2.2,
               G31_comp IS NULL, 3.1,
               G32_comp IS NULL, 3.2,
               G33_comp IS NULL, 3.3,
               G4_comp IS NULL, 4,
               1=1, 0) AS Current_Gate, 
    DSUM ("Goal", "qry_Gate_Status", "Gate <= " & Current_Gate & " AND PR 
    = '" & PR & "'") AS Target_Days, 
   (DATE() - G21_Start) AS Elapsed, 
   IIF (Elapsed > Target_Days, "Overdue", "On Track") AS Contract_Health
FROM qry_Gate_Status_Extended;
```

Result:

```
PR     Genesis_Date  Current_Gate  Target_Days  Elapsed  Contract_Health
AA         3/8/2019           2.1  45                90  Overdue
AB         1/1/2019           3.1  73               156  On Track
BB         5/1/2019           2.2  59                36  On Track
BC        9/19/2018           2.1  45               260  On Track
```

When `Elapsed` is greater than `Target_Days` the `Contract_Health` should be `"Overdue"` else it should be `"On Track"`.

As you see the results are not consistent.  One thing I do notice is the `Target_Days` (result of `DSUM`) is left justified like a text field instead of right justified as a number.  I must be overlooking something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good and carefully observed  So you should convert the textual value into a numerical before comparing. Otherwise alphabetical comparison (letter for letter) orders 4 < 9, 7 > 1, 5 > 3, and so on.

Comment: I'm still wondering why DSUM did not return a number?  I guess I assumed a "SUM" is a numerical value instead of a alpha character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the VAL() function to convert what I thought was a number to an actual number and it worked.

```
VAL(DSUM ("Goal", "qry_Gate_Status", "Gate <= " & Current_Gate & " AND PR 
= '" & PR & "'")) AS Target_Days
```

Thanks for the tip!!!  You guys rock!!!

Comment: Good style to convert values as early as possible (from the source).

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression to convert text (here: value of field `Target_Days`) into a number before comparing:

```
IIF ( Elapsed > VAL(Target_Days), "Overdue", "On Track")
```

For details of **VAL** function see:

- [WE schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_val.asp)
- [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Val-function-to-convert-text-values-to-numbers-05DCE9AC-1687-4EED-BC81-CC46DB2767A5)